# Voltage follower for signal generator ground issue?

Tags: operational-amplifier, grounding, virtual-ground, dual-supply

I'm trying to amplify the signal from a [signal generator](https://www.aimtti.com/product-category/dc-power-supplies/aim-el-rseries) to get a high frequency AC current in a resistor. My circuit is below. However whatever voltage I put on the signal, the output seems to be ~3.8V, which is the voltage difference between the signal ground and the resistor ground. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using a [dual power supply](https://www.aimtti.com/product-category/dc-power-supplies/aim-el-rseries) to create the two power rails for the op amp ([TLE2081](https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=TLE2081CP)), and tying the - of the + supply with the + of the - to create my common ground for the system. Both signal generator and power supply are run from the same adaptor plugged into one mains socket.

Many thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting the generator output to op-amp input like that is not correct.

The signal generator ground is not connected to the common ground of the powersupply/opamp circuit.

The op-amp output to feedback into negative input can't work as the op-amp would like to drive both of it's input pins to same voltage but connecting the generator to both op-amp inputs prevents the feedback from working.

Answer (score 1):

The signal generator ground must be connected to the power supply common/ground, and not to the op-amp negative input.